# Shall we set official RLU.SE retagging procedure?

Tags: discussion, retagging, guidelines

How shall we perform retagging here?

Answer (score 2):

There is a procedure described at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/retag-request/info:

> About `retag-request`
>
> This tag denotes a request for help to retag a set of questions. Note that the moderator capacity of merging tags is simply an extended application of retagging, and thus requesting that one tag be merged into another is simply a different flavor of retag-request.
>
> Use this tag in combination with site specific tag(s) to which the request applies (such as stackoverflow, meta, or area51-discussion). Also use either of these required tags:
>
> `support`, if the request is indisputable and/or demands moderator assistance
>
> `discussion`, to discuss how to retag the set of questions, if at all

I suggest just following it. So we post a `retag-request`-tagged question with the `support` tag if the situation is obvious or `discussion` if we need to discuss the suggested retagging. Plus we need to add the RLU.SE tag.

Comment: Do we have a tag for this SE? What should it look like?